# Scrolling text box in Keynote.app?

Tags: keynote

Can I place a scrolling text box on a slide in Keynote?

By default, the "Text" items do not scroll. Any added text that flows beyond the edge of the slide is hidden (truncated).

Answer (score 1):

That seems to be possible, at least if you can accept it to be "animated", and scroll on command: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HHl72gfDl94

Comment: Thanks for the Answer. I'm looking for a simple scroll box with a scroll bar. During my presentation I want to peruse a list of a thousand phrases. The animated tricks are too awkward for that.